# ActiveX control in WPF

Tags: wpf, interop, activex

I am using a thrid party SDk to display video in my WPF application.
This requires me to add a control which is part of the SDK to the UI in order to display the video. I added the control to my WPF using the windows form host

```
 ImageViewerControl _imageViewerControl = ClientControl.Instance.GenerateImageViewerControl();
 WindowsFormsHost host = new WindowsFormsHost();
 host.Child = _imageViewerControl;
 grid1.Children.Add(host);
```

When I checked the grid1.children.count it is 1, also the _imageViewerControl is not null. Yet I do not see anything loaded on the UI.

But when I use WindowsForm everything works fine. What should I look for?